# Determining continuity between subsets of topological space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose X is a topological space, say built on the set of all integers.  It seems to me the notion of topological continuity (and continuous function) is defined between two topological spaces.  I am interested in the topological continuity between subsets of given, same topology (in this case X).  Of course, there exists continuous function between two open sets of the X, but suppose A is a proper subset of X such that we do not know if A is open or closed...

I want to know if there exists a continuous function from that subset A to an open set U, which then shows A is indeed an open set of the X as long as continuous function from A to U is surjective (the inverse image of U is entire A).  If such onto continuous function exists from A to U, how do we know if A is an open set with respect to topology X, or A as a subspace topology of X (meaning the inverse image of U, which is entire A, is open by A considered as a subspace topology).  I want to believe that such function shows A is an open set with respect to topology X, and not as a subspace topology, but could we make such claim for sure?

Summary, I am interested in verifying whether a subset of topological space is open or not by showing the existence of surjective continuous function that set to another open set.

Answer (score 2):

If $A \subseteq X$ and $U \subseteq X$ open, having a surjective continuous map $A \longrightarrow U$ is not enough to conclude that $A$ is open in $X$. Here's a counterexample. Take $X = \{a, b\}$ with the topology $\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$. Then let $U = \{a\}$ and $A = \{b\}$. The topologies on $U, A$ are necessarily discrete so the map $A \longrightarrow U$ via $b \mapsto a$ (the only possible map here) is continuous. In fact, it's a homeomorphism. However, $A$ is still not open in $X$. In fact, this map actually extends to all of $X$ via the constant map $f(x)= a$. This is a continuous surjection with $f[A] = U$ but $A$ is still not open in $X$. You are, however, completely right to say that it is open in $A$ itself under the subspace topology.

Comment: What if both A and U have sufficiently large cardinality?  Or if they have more than one element, and honeomeopgism between A and U does not exist?  What would be enough to confirm A is open if we do not know A is open or not just by the definition of topology?

Comment: I think you can find counterexamples of arbitrarily large cardinality. For example, take $X$ to be $U \coprod A$ as a set and topologize it via $\{\emptyset, U, X\}$. So long as $|A| \geq |U|$ the same sort of thing will happen. Also, the lack of a homeomorphism is, if anything, a weaker condition so I doubt it'll do anything for you. Ultimately, the problem is that $f^{-1}[f[A]] \neq A$ in general. What you need here in injectivity. Indeed, if we had an injective map $f: X \longrightarrow X$ with $f[A] = U$, then $A = f^{-1}[f[a]] = f^{-1}[U]$ is open.

Comment: How can there be injective map when the cardinality of A is strictly greater than U?  There exists injective continuous map from U to A of course.

Comment: And f(A) = U means surjection from A to U.

Comment: Why is $|A| > |U|$? You only said there is a surjection, so $|A| \geq |U|$. You asked for a condition where $A$ is necessarily open and I gave one: the existence of an injective map $f: X \longrightarrow X$ such that $f[A] = U$. This is, in particular, a bijection $A \longrightarrow U$. There may be other conditions that determine if $A$ is open, but the existence of just a continuous surjection is not enough.

Comment: I apologize. The cardinality of A is strictly greater than U.  But what you stated is that basically A must be homeomorphic to U right?

Comment: So for one, what I stated is a sufficient condition but is not necessary. There could be weaker/different conditions which will allow us to conclude that $A$ is open. Also, the existence of a continuous bijection $A \longrightarrow U$ does not imply that they are homeomorphic. Indeed, the inverse of a continuous map need not be continuous. For example, take $f: [0, 2 \pi) \longrightarrow S^1$ via $t \mapsto e^{it}$. This is a continuous bijection but its inverse is not continuous. If it were, then $f^{-1}[S^1] = [0, 2 \pi)$ is compact - which it is not.

Answer (score 1):

It can fail badly. Let

$$A=(-1,0)\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\left(\frac1{2n+1},\frac1{2n}\right)\;;$$

clearly $A$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and has cardinality $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$. Let

$$U=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\;;$$

$U$ is not open in $\Bbb R$, and it is countable, so $|U|<|A|$.

Let

$$f:A\to U:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x\in(-1,0)\\
\frac1n,&\text{if }x\in\left(\frac1{2n+1},\frac1{2n}\right)\;;
\end{cases}$$

then $f$ is surjective and continuous.